# Authentication and Authorization through a Web API Service Layer accessed by an ASP.NET web application and an iOS mobile app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am about to start working on a new ASP.NET MVC web application that I intend to build an iOS mobile version of as well.

I am planning on using MVC 4 Web API as a service layer that will sit in front of the business layer and be accessed by both the web application and the mobile application.

I am a little confused however about how I will implement authentication and authorization in this architecture.

Normally in an MVC application, once a user submits proper credentials, I would make a call to

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
```

Which will create a cookie that will then be passed back and forth from one request to another to maintain a user's session in the application.

I'm confused as to how this will function through a service layer when accessed from the web application.  Or how it will function when the service is called from the mobile application.

Comment: Here is a good walkthrough on using tokens to secure WebAPI: http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/

Answer (score 0):

You could design your Web API in such a manner that it would require the forms authentication cookie should be sent on each request. You would then use this cookie to extract the username of the currently authenticated user from it.

But when designing an API it is usually better to use some other means of authentication than cookies. For example you could use the `Authorization` HTTP header where the client will be required to send the encrypted value of a forms authentication ticket.

You might also take a look at the [`following article`](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/) about token based security.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend getting into the "your own token" business. Use something that is proven, e.g. JWT tokens. Or have a look at this article for starters: http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/dog-fooding-our-api-authentication